# Is it possible to let users edit comment until someone has actually replied to it to maintain the context

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments

I have faced the issue several times and may be other users as well. 
Whenever I post a comment to SE sites, it stays editable till 5 minutes only. And often I jump back into my comment at 5 and 1/2 minutes, start editing my comment for a better explanation and when I just try to save my edits SE informs me that 5 minutes is over. Isn't it pretty annoying?

Can't it be like the following:

1. When a user adds a comment directly to a question/answer, the
   question/answer becomes it's parent reference.
2. Every comment itself has a "comment" link by itself that lets users
   to add a new comment in context of the current comment. The current
   comment becomes the parent reference of the new comment.
3. If a comment is deleted, all it's referenced comments point to the
   question/answer as applicable.
4. A user is allowed to edit his/her comment until any new comment is
   posted, referencing it.

I think this would make SE users life a little better than before and would also solve the issue with 5 minutes timeout, many users might be facing.

### EDIT:

To better explain my question, I am **not really worried about the 5 minutes timeout**, many of the users might have actually perceived. It's actually about maintaining the context in comments of a question/answer. The 5 minutes timeout should automatically be handled as a consequence.

Comment: So..... That feels like a pretty big overhaul for the comments, considering they are second class citizens here.... + i don't think that the 5 minutes time out is that big of an issue in itself. Comments are ephemereal and unimportant in the grand scheme of Stack

Comment: @Patrice obviously they are the second class citizens but they are the ones who drives the users to right direction and still highly underrated :(

Comment: If you need extended discussion then that should take place in chat. Nested comments on questions would get extremely messy.

Comment: When editing comments, just be quick (5 minutes seems to be a small time frame).

Comment: @AyanSengupta and in what way would a higher window to edit change that? I don't think it would bethat much help in changing that perception

Comment: @Patrice you might have missed my point. My issue is not only with the lower timeframe. The point is in loosing the context. But anyway.

Comment: @AyanSengupta but with your new system there is no more context then currently. Withyour new system, if i delete the original comment as much is lost asit is currently (and your title makes it seem like your biggest issue is withthe edit window)

Comment: @Patrice sorry for my clumsy question title. But if you think of the present system, I think it has the same flaw you were talking about. So it shouldn't make any difference in that context.

Comment: @AyanSengupta i said myself the current system has that flaw. Why should we change it if this isn't a change for the better? You're making the whole system a lot more complicated for no added benefit. I think there are better uses of dev time.

Comment: @Patrice may be you are way too much busy to overlook my point of "added benefit" that I have already mentioned as "maintaining context" and that might come really handy for "future users" or else I guess devs here are little too lazy to adopt something new and loves anticipating outcomes. Don't wanna waste my time anymore. Cheers and keep up the spirit!

Comment: @AyanSengupta it's simply that i dont see how your suggested system preserves more context than the current one. Comments can become part of a chain as people reply to each other, and deleting one breaks context as much as it would in your new system. You seem to have added a layer of complexity just for "context". And your context is pretty much the same that we currently have. A comment chain is a comment chain, no matter if each comment is referencing another or just pinging a specific user. You seem to just hammer "context" without seeing it's not an improvement over what we currently have

Answer (score 10):

Yeah, it's totally possible. Also adds complexity to what is currently a simple system.

If *no one has replied*, just delete your comment and post a new one. No time limit on this! If this doesn't work (for instance, because someone else has a reply in progress and posts it as you're writing your update), then editing would also be problematic.

Comment: I know what you are talking about. Obviously it incurs some overhead. Unfortunately things get complicated for users when they see a past question/answer with lots of unrelated comments pulled together. Possibly most of them are meant to improve the quality of the answer. But their sequence becomes totally misleading. Certainly, as a new commenter I can delete my comment after 5 mins and rewrite but that doesn't solve the riddle with the context for a future reader.

Comment: @AyanSengupta but how would the system know your comment wasn't replied too?  Not everyone knows the '@' syntax

Comment: @psubsee2003 c'mon...you must be kiddin! After FB and Twitter broke through, at least 80% of their users know the usage of '@' and I guess 40% of them are not even technical. And then SO is a site for technical persons and it needs minimum reputation to add a comment in SO for a technical person and that minimum reputation can only be earned by that technical person only when s/he has some familiarity with the flow of the site. Do you still believe it really matters? As a side-note, I'm really sorry but I couldn't understand what you were trying to convey. Could you please explain?